# The function is undefined. (recursion)

Tags: function, recursion, lisp, undefined

I am writing a simple member function that returns the value associated with that member. The first line of the conditional (to test if the first value is the one we're looking for) works fine, but the recursive part (to test parts of the list that are further along) returns an error every time.

Here is my function:

```
(defun mem (prop L)
  (cond
    ((eq (caar L) prop) (print cadar L)))
    (t (mem (prop (cdr L))))))                   // error is on this line!
```

So, if I enter

```
(mem `i `((i 1) (j 2)))
```

it correctly returns 1. However, if I enter

```
(mem `j `((i 1) (j 2)))
```

it returns an error that "function prop is undefined."

How do I let the program know that prop isn't a function, but is just an input parameter?

This is my first lisp program, so I'm assuming the answer is incredibly simple, but I have tried many things and have yet to succeed.

Comment: I don't see how your function can return 1, when you're trying to print the value of a nonexistent variable called `cadar`, using the value of variable `L` as the destination stream.

Answer (score 4):

The problem in particular is the snippet: `(prop (cdr L))`. This tries to call `prop`, passing it `(cdr L)`. To pass it as an argument to `mem`, simply leave out the extra parentheses: `(mem prop (cdr L))`.

If you're having a problem figuring out where to put parentheses in general, note that Lisp syntax is very similar to mathematical syntax for functions, except the function goes on the inside of the parentheses (and you use spaces instead of commas, but that isn't a problem here). For example, written in mathematical notation, you have: `mem(prop(cdr(L)))`, instead of `mem(prop, cdr(L))`.

#### Other Issues

It looks like you have an extra parentheses after the first branch of the `cond`, which ends it early. Use an editor/IDE with parentheses matching to catch this sort of error. Emacs does it, as does [DrRacket](http://racket-lang.org/). The former can be used with Common LISP via [SLIME](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/) (search the web for set-up instructions for your platform), while the latter readily supports Scheme.

The semicolon (";") is the comment character used in most LISPs.

`print` isn't necessary for this function, and (depending on its behavior) may be incorrect. In some LISPs (e.g. Common LISP), it returns its argument, but in others it may return nil or the instance of some void type.

[Quasiquote](http://www.cs.washington.edu/education/courses/cse341/04wi/lectures/14-scheme-quote.html) (aka [backquote](http://cl-cookbook.sourceforge.net/macros.html), backtick) is also unnecessary. Quasiquote lets you quote some symbols, while others (those prefixed with a comma) are replaced with their values. Since you don't need substitution in the quoted expressions, a plain quote will work: `(mem 'j '((i 1) (j 2)))`.

For readability, insert more whitespace between closing and opening parentheses.